# Heap has been corrupted when using std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, opengl, unique-ptr

I've been working on a Quake 3 BSP Loader in OpenGL and C++.

And I've ran into a problem, when I run my code. I get a problem, it says "heap has been corrupted!" in debug mode. I have commented the line it corrupts on. My comment is 'gives me the error at this line "Heap has been corrupted"'

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <glm/vec3.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <vector>   
#include "map.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <memory>
#include "game_manager.h"
#include <thread>

bool KikoBSP::load_map(std::string file_name)
{
    this->file.open(file_name.c_str(), std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

    if (this->file.is_open())
    {
        this->file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&this->header), sizeof(this->header));

        std::unique_ptr<BSPEntities> ents(new BSPEntities);
        ents->ents_array = new char[this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::ENTITIES].length];

        this->num_textures = this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::TEXTURES].length / sizeof(BSPTexture);
        this->num_planes = this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::PLANES].length / sizeof(BSPPlane);
        this->num_textures = this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::TEXTURES].length / sizeof(BSPTexture);
        this->num_nodes = this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::NODES].length / sizeof(BSPNode);
        this->num_leafs = this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::LEAFS].length / sizeof(BSPLeaf);
        this->num_leaf_faces = this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::LEAF_FACES].length / sizeof(BSPLeafFace);
        this->num_leaf_brushes = this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::LEAF_BRUSHES].length / sizeof(BSPLeafBrush);
        this->num_models = this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::MODELS].length / sizeof(BSPModel);
        this->num_brushes = this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::BRUSHES].length / sizeof(BSPBrush);
        this->num_brush_sides = this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::BRUSHSIDES].length / sizeof(BSPBrushSides);
        this->num_vertexes = this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::VERTEXES].length / sizeof(BSPVerts);
        this->num_meshverts = this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::MESHVERTS].length / sizeof(BSPMeshVerts);
        this->num_effects = this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::EFFECTS].length / sizeof(BSPEffects);
        this->num_faces = this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::FACES].length / sizeof(BSPFaces);

        std::unique_ptr<BSPTexture[]> textures(new BSPTexture[this->num_textures]);
        std::unique_ptr<BSPPlane[]> planes(new BSPPlane[this->num_planes]);
        std::unique_ptr<BSPNode[]> nodes(new BSPNode[this->num_nodes]);
        std::unique_ptr<BSPLeaf[]> leafs(new BSPLeaf[this->num_leafs]);
        std::unique_ptr<BSPLeafFace[]> leaf_faces(new BSPLeafFace[this->num_leaf_faces]);
        std::unique_ptr<BSPLeafBrush[]> leaf_brushes(new BSPLeafBrush[this->num_leaf_brushes]);
        std::unique_ptr<BSPModel[]> models(new BSPModel[this->num_models]);
        std::unique_ptr<BSPBrush[]> brushes(new BSPBrush[this->num_brushes]);
        std::unique_ptr<BSPBrushSides[]> brush_sides(new BSPBrushSides[this->num_brush_sides]);
        std::unique_ptr<BSPVerts[]> vertexes(new BSPVerts[this->num_vertexes]);
        std::unique_ptr<BSPMeshVerts[]> mesh_verts(new BSPMeshVerts[this->num_mesh_verts]);
        std::unique_ptr<BSPEffects[]> effects(new BSPEffects[this->num_effects]);
        std::unique_ptr<BSPFaces[]> faces(new BSPFaces[this->num_faces]);

        this->file.seekg(this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::ENTITIES].offset);
        this->file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(ents->ents_array), this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::ENTITIES].length);

        this->file.seekg(this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::TEXTURES].offset);
        this->file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(textures.get()), this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::TEXTURES].length);

        this->file.seekg(this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::PLANES].offset);
        this->file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(planes.get()), this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::PLANES].length);

        this->file.seekg(this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::NODES].offset);
        this->file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(nodes.get()), this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::NODES].length);

        this->file.seekg(this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::LEAFS].offset);
        this->file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(leafs.get()), this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::LEAFS].length);

        this->file.seekg(this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::LEAF_FACES].offset);
        this->file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(leaf_faces.get()), this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::LEAF_FACES].length);

        this->file.seekg(this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::LEAF_BRUSHES].offset);
        this->file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(leaf_brushes.get()), this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::LEAF_BRUSHES].length);

        this->file.seekg(this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::MODELS].offset);
        this->file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(models.get()), this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::MODELS].length);

        this->file.seekg(this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::BRUSHES].offset);
        this->file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(brushes.get()), this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::BRUSHES].length);

        this->file.seekg(this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::BRUSHSIDES].offset);
        this->file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(brush_sides.get()), this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::BRUSHSIDES].length);

        this->file.seekg(this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::VERTEXES].offset);
        this->file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(vertexes.get()), this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::VERTEXES].length);

        this->file.seekg(this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::MESHVERTS].offset);
        this->file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(mesh_verts.get()), this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::MESHVERTS].length);

        this->file.seekg(this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::EFFECTS].offset);
        this->file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(effects.get()), this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::EFFECTS].length);

        this->file.seekg(this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::FACES].offset);
        this->file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(faces.get()), this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::FACES].length);

        std::printf("BSP VERSION: '%s'\n", this->header.magic);

        if (std::strncmp(this->header.magic, "IBSP", 4) == 0)
        {
            std::printf("SUCCESS: VALID BSP FORMAT!\n");
        }
        else
        {
            std::printf("ERROR: INVALID BSP FORMAT!\n");

            return false;
        }

        std::printf("this->num_of_verts == %i\n", this->num_vertexes);

        for (int32_t x = 0; x <= this->num_vertexes; x++)
        {
            this->vertices.push_back(vertexes.get()[x].position.x);
            this->vertices.push_back(vertexes.get()[x].position.y); /* gives me the error at this line "Heap has been corrupted" */
            this->vertices.push_back(vertexes.get()[x].position.z);

            this->colors.push_back((float)x); /* doesnt follow my code style (using C-style cast), sorry!! I copied this from my old project ;) */
        }

        std::printf("this->vertices.size() == %i\n", this->vertices.size());

        this->shader.load_shader("bsp.vs", "bsp.fs");

        glGenVertexArrays(1, &this->vao);

        glBindVertexArray(this->vao);

        glGenBuffers(1, &this->vbo);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->vertices.size() * sizeof(float), &this->vertices.front(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glGenBuffers(1, &this->color_vbo);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->color_vbo);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->colors.size() * sizeof(float), &this->colors.front(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        this->coord3d = glGetAttribLocation(this->shader.program, "coord3d");
        this->mvp = glGetUniformLocation(this->shader.program, "mvp");
        this->attrib_color = glGetAttribLocation(this->shader.program, "v_color");

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->vbo);
        glVertexAttribPointer(this->coord3d, // attribute
            3,                 // number of elements per vertex, here (R,G,B)
            GL_FLOAT,          // the currentBlock of each element
            GL_FALSE,          // take our values as-is
            0,                 // no extra data between each position
            nullptr               // offset of first element
        );

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->color_vbo);
        glVertexAttribPointer(this->attrib_color,
            3,
            GL_FLOAT,
            GL_FALSE,
            0,
            nullptr
        );

        glBindVertexArray(0);

        glVertexAttrib3fv(this->attrib_color, this->colors.data());

        std::printf("size of vector = %i\n", this->vertices.size());

        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        std::printf("ERROR: COULDN'T OPEN FILE!\n");

        return false;
    }

    return false;
}


void KikoBSP::render(glm::vec3 position)
{
    glBindVertexArray(this->vao);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(this->coord3d);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(this->attrib_color);

    glm::mat4 model = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(position.x, position.y, position.z));
    glm::mat4 mvp = game_manager->projection * game_manager->view * model;
    glUniformMatrix4fv(this->mvp, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(mvp));

    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, this->vertices.size());

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(this->coord3d);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(this->attrib_color);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

void KikoBSP::cleanup_map()
{
    /* OUTDATED FUNCTION BACK WHEN I WAS MANUALLY MANAGING MEMORY */
}
```

However, the error goes away, when I take off these lines:

```
    this->file.seekg(this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::EFFECTS].offset);
    this->file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(effects.get()), this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::EFFECTS].length);

    this->file.seekg(this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::FACES].offset);
    this->file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(faces.get()), this->header.lumps[BSPLUMPS::FACES].length);
```

Which leads me to believe the Heap is overflowing with all the allocated memory.
I also believe this, because when I was manually managing memory. I ran into the same problem as well. So I switched to unique_ptrs, and I'm still getting the same problem! :(

Anyone here have any ideas? Thanks! :)

Comment: `unique_ptr` will not help you if you write outside of allocated memory and trash the book-keeping structures. Instead of `std::unique_ptr<BSPTexture[]> textures(new BSPTexture[this->num_textures]);` switch to a `std::vector<BSPTexture> textures(this->num_textures)` and use `std::vector::at` at least for the short term. Ugly performance hit if you do this for realz, but `at` will throw an exception if you march outside of bounds. You can also write your own array wrapper  that traps invalid access in a custom cooked `operator[]` and this may be easier swap back and forth than `at`.

Comment: I have some bad news for you: just because a C++ program crashes at a particular line doesn't mean that's where the bug is. Heap corruption can occur at any time without having the program immediately crash. After all, merely writing to an invalid pointer that still points to valid memory, but belonging to some other unrelated structure, will not result in an immediate crash; but the program will continue to run until it tries to use the corrupted structure, and then crash. Your bug can be anywhere in your code. Welcome to C++.

Comment: One thing that is sure... is that when you have that much repeatitive code, it is time to put the **DRY** principle in action. There is absolutely no reason why you would extract repetitive code in a template function and replace 4 lines with one per object type. **Also, your function is way too long**. Read about **SRP** too. And in my opinion, it is weird that you have so much local `unique_ptr`. I don't see much local use inside the function and if used outside, I think it would be best to have one `class` holding them all. In any case, it would be a good idea to refactor your code...

Comment: By the way, the idea to read binary like that is fragile... as it is not portable and depends on types on which you might not have control. Are you defining types like `BSPTexture`? Are you sure they are POD types? If not, you might have undefined behavior. If you really want to write such code, at least add some `static_assert` to your code to ensure that the types does not have virtual table, is of expected size etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got incorrect loop condition:

```
for (int32_t x = 0; x <= this->num_vertexes; x++)
```

In its last iteration `x == num_vertexes`, which means you are trying to read the value beyond the array boundary. Check with the debugger - you'll see that x takes this value when the heap corruption happens. Also, I'm pretty sure it's not the line you've marked causing heap corruption, but the line before - many debuggers show the next line to be executed, not the one being executed.

BTW I'm not familiar with the classes you use and thus can't say for sure, but you're most likely abusing the use of `std::unique_ptr`. Just use `std::vector` instead of unique pointer to dynamic array - it's way simplier, easier to use and should work exactly the way you expect.

Comment: This is a bug in your code... so you don't have to give it a try but apply the fix. And if it still does not work, then you would have problem elsewhere. In any case, you should accept this answer as it really fix a problem in your code.